# Yama depiction on various Tankas

Tags: vajrayana, samsara

I saw many images of the circle of existence represented with Yama, the lord of death, with a tiger skin and a third eye. Why is he represented in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is a depiction of [Mahakala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahakala), rather than [Yama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama).

In the Chinese Buddhist Encyclopedia page [Mahakala is a Protector of all Tibetan Buddhism](http://chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/Mahakala_is_a_Protector_of_all_Tibetan_Buddhism), we find this info:

> The Form varies according to the different teaching lineages. For
> example, there is the two-armed, big-mouthed Mahakala Bernakchen of
> the Karma Kagyu, the four-armed Mahakala who is protector of the
> Drikung Kagyu, and six-armed Mahakala of the Gelugpas described below.
> They are not all wrathful forms of Chenresi [Skt.: Avalokiteshvara)
> although:
>
> > "There is an emanation of Avalokiteshvara which arose in the Form
> > of Mahakala and this is the Shangpa Kagyu Mahakala with one face and
> > six arms, in a standing posture. This Form was later adopted by
> > Tsongkhapa and followers as the main protector of the Gelugpa School.
> >
> > Mahakalas can arise from various sources namely Vajradhara and
> > the Anuttarayoga Tantras but are not generically Avalokiteshvara."
> >
> > ~ Jeff Watt, Himalayan Art
>
> There is a white one associated with prosperity, and also a eunuch and
> some feminine forms, but it is incorrectly held that there are 75
> variants.

Regarding the symbolism around Mahakala:

> Symbolism of Mahakala in the 6-armed Manifestation:
>
> The Protector's Body is midnight blue, symbolic of the changeless
> Dharmakaya.
>
> **His three eyes symbolize his Knowledge of the past, present and
> future, and also the manifestation of the three bodies of Buddha.**
>
> **The crown adorned with five skulls symbolizes the transformation of
> the five poisons of Anger, desire, Ignorance, jealousy and pride into
> The Five Wisdoms.**
>
> His six arms symbolize the attainment of the six Perfections:
> Generosity, Patience, Morality, Diligence, Meditation and Wisdom. The
> kartika or triku [or trigu, pron. tigu] the Ritual curved knife, cuts
> Attachment to ego.
>
> The kapila or skull bowl filled with blood symbolizes the subjugation
> of the maras or Evil ones. (An alternate interpretation can be found
> in other contexts.)
>
> The rosary symbolizes his continuous activity for the benefit of
> beings.
>
> The Damaru or hand-drum symbolizes his Power over the Dakinis. (Also,
> different interpretations in other contexts.)
>
> His trident symbolizes his Power over The Three Kayas -- the spheres
> of desire, Form and formlessness. (An alternate interpretation can
> also be found.)
>
> The lasso binds those who break their vows.
>
> His two feet are the means and the Wisdom to accomplish his task. That
> his left leg is straight and his right leg bent symbolize his
> accomplishment of the benefit to oneself and to others. He tramples on
> a vinayaka, to symbolize his destruction and dispersal of great
> obstacles.
>
> The sun on which he stands symbolizes his illumination of the darkness
> of Ignorance.
>
> His Lotus seat symbolizes purity undefiled by Samsara.
>
> The surrounding blazing Fire symbolizes his activity that consumes
> neurotic states.
>
> **The tiger skin stands for Purification of desire; the elephant skin
> for Purification of pride, and the snake, for the Purification of
> Anger.**
>
> His other ornaments together symbolize that he has all the qualities
> of a Buddha.
>
> The material about the symbolism of 6-armed Mahakala derives from a
> Gelugpa sadhana (Ritual) of Tara that includes an Offering to
> Mahakala.

Comment: The snake represents anger -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_poisons -- so I expect that the "tiger" and the "elephant" represent desire and pride respectively ... and their skins represent being purified thereof (I'm not sure why, I suppose it's to do with the animal being killed, emptied, vanquished, disappeared, harmless). I've also seen "elephants" before representing "pride" -- https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rutting+elephants+of+pride%22 -- in 12th century South Indian poetry, but maybe that shows that's a standard idiom. The tiger's representing "desire" seems plausible too.

Comment: Thank You. Also if sometimes i read the Chinese Encyclopedia website, i found it sometimes lacking of original sources . For example http://www.khandro.net/deity_Mahakala.htm is the original source used to describe in detail Mahakala as a protector of Vajrayana Buddhism.